# stuck without [.] on level 12

Tags: vim-adventures

At level 12 there are two red doors.
The right door contains the dot operation, the left door contains the rest of the level.

If I follow the the left door, I quickly get stuck at the 'isOver' puzzle,  since the dot operation is needed here.  However, I am not able to go back to the red doors in order to enter the left one, since the text is removed and I cannot cross the gap.

How do I get back to the red doors so I can get the dot operator?

[image]

Comment: No idea personally, but found [this guide](https://github.com/pepers/vim-adventures) on GitHub that may help.

Comment: Thanks!  the guide helped me figure out i need the dot operator.  It seems to assume you have it once you enter the left door.

Comment: Excellent; glad it helped. You'll probably have to answer your own question unless another vim user comes along. I could try, but I don't understand even though I'm a programming nerd, and I'd probably mess it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed the creator.  Turns out this is a bug. You are supposed to be able to go back to the doors,  but somehow the text has ended up in the wrong place for me. I got a savegame created for me so I could continue on my adventure.